# How to implement a .m script in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

i have written a m-function in a script. This function script simulates behavior of a system. 
Now i want to implement it in a Simulink Modell. The function has several inputs and several outputs. Actually i find the user-defined functions, but they all have one input and one output.

Do somebody now how i can implement the m.file into the simulink modell with more than one inputs and outputs?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the user defined functions allow multiple inputs.

For instance, the [MATLAB Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block has a default of:

```
function y = fcn(u)

y = u;
```

Which can be changed to have 2 outputs and 3 inputs (for instance) just like any other MATLAB function:

```
function [out1,out2] = fcn(in1,in2,in3)

out1 = in1;
out2 = in2 + in3;
```